# Numpy reshape - automatic filling or removal

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I would like to find a reshape function that is able to transform my arrays of different dimensions in arrays of the same dimension. Let me explain it:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[1,2,3,3],[1,2,3,3]],[[1,2,3,3],[1,2,3,3]]])
b = np.array([[[1,2,3,3],[1,2,3,3]],[[1,2,3,3],[1,2,3,3]],[[1,2,3,3],[1,2,3,4]]])
c = np.array([[[1,2,3,3],[1,2,3,3]]])
```

I would like to be able to make `b,c` shapes equal to `a` shape. However, `np.reshape` throws an error because as explained here ([Numpy resize or Numpy reshape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985692/numpy-resize-or-numpy-reshape)) the function is explicitly made to handle the same dimensions.

I would like some version of that function that adds zeros at the start of the first dimension if the shape is smaller or remove the start if the shape is bigger. My example will look like this:

```
b = np.array([[[1,2,3,3],[1,2,3,3]],[[1,2,3,3],[1,2,3,4]]])
c = np.array([[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],[[1,2,3,3],[1,2,3,3]]])
```

Do I need to write my own function to do that?

Comment: There is a `np.pad` function.  But that might not be any easier to use than the answer.  There are so many different ways of padding that it's hard to provide a general purpose function.   In your case, you do the odd thing of padding at the start!  In the long run you'll be better of understanding the provided answer than looking for a function that does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to above solution but will also work also if lower dimensions don't match

```py
def custom_reshape(a, b):
    result = np.zeros_like(a).ravel()
    result[-min(a.size, b.size):] = b.ravel()[-min(a.size, b.size):]
    return result.reshape(a.shape)

custom_reshape(a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write a function like this:

```
def align(a,b):
    out = np.zeros_like(a)
    x = min(a.shape[0], b.shape[0])
    out[-x:] = b[-x:]

    return out
```

Output:

```
align(a,b)
# array([[[1, 2, 3, 3],
#         [1, 2, 3, 3]],

#        [[1, 2, 3, 3],
#         [1, 2, 3, 4]]])

align(a,c)
# array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0, 0]],

#        [[1, 2, 3, 3],
#         [1, 2, 3, 3]]])
```

Comment: That is a smart solution. Would it be possible to extend it to any shape, basically to recreate the exact shape of `a`.

Comment: Should be possible with `x = np.min( a.shape, b.shape)`.